# Facebook Connect Won't Validate

Tags: facebook, validation, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to get my Facebook Connect code to validate, but it won't.  I think the problem is that their xmlns page isn't loading.  I have the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

But http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml isn't found.  Does anyone have a copy of what it should be?  Is there a different URL i should use?

Answer (score 3):

The XML namespace doesn't need to actually exist, they are just a way to qualify elements and attributes.  If you're interested (this is unrelated to your issue), there is more about XML namespaces [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/)

Facebook seems to have a pretty straightforward page setup here: [FB Connect](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Trying_Out_Facebook_Connect), and it's laid out step by step.  Have you checked this out?

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, the namespace URL is a red-herring. It's the DTD (as specified in the DOCTYPE) that is validated against.

If you really want to validate your pages that use XFBML, you will need to validate against a custom DTD. And, as far as I'm aware, Facebook don't publish a DTD for XFBML themselves, so you'll have to write one yourself (probably only for the elements/attributes that you're actually using).

It's not actually as tricky as it sounds; [here's an **A List Apart** article on how to validate against a custom DTD](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customdtd/).

Note also that messing around with your DOCTYPE declaration may do funny things with regards to knocking (older) browsers into quirks mode.

So you can get it to validate; it's just up to you whether it's worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook XHTML does not validate.

Answer (score 0):

XFBML - why did they have to be different?  Nobody will care enough to petition them on this until a couple years from now and then W3C will re-write their standard to include XFBML or Facebook will be forced to re-write in a more compatible format.  Why not use ID's or rel attributes to make their script work?  That would allow a 100% valid format that would play nice with all browsers and CMS out there.  Maybe they were worried about blog pages without root access making FB-based scams?