# Where can I find sample XHTML5 source codes?

Tags: html

Where can I find sample **X**HTML 5 pages? I mainly want to know if it is possible to mix and match XHTML 5 with other XML languages just like XHTML 1 or not. For example is something like this valid in XHTML 5?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?" 
          "WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?">
<html xmlns="WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
  <title><ui:insert name="title">Default title</ui:insert></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
    <ui:insert name="header">
        <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>
    </ui:insert>
</div>


<div id="left">
  <ui:insert name="navigation" >
    <ui:include src="navigation.xhtml"/>
  </ui:insert>
</div>


<div id="center">
  <br />
  <span class="titleText"> <ui:insert name="title" /> </span>
  <hr />
  <ui:insert name="content">
    <div>
    <ui:include src="content.xhtml"/>  
    </div>
  </ui:insert>
</div>

<div id="right">
  <ui:insert name="news">
    <ui:include src="news.xhtml"/>
  </ui:insert>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <ui:insert name="footer">
    <ui:include src="footer.xhtml"/>  
  </ui:insert>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a doctype at all. They are not designed to cope with namespaces and don't serve any useful purpose in XML. (In HTML, they are necessary to get into standards mode.) If you really insist on having one, for whatever reason, use simply `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

As for the namespace:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
```

as you are already using, I assume.

As you see, there is no information about the version you're using. That's because you don't need it. For validation, you can pick your target in the UI, and browsers have never looked at versions. That is, in browsers, there is no such thing as HTML3.2 or HTML4.01 or HTML5, just "HTML", and no XHTML1.0, XHTML1.1 or XHTML5, only "XHTML". Today, those consist mainly of HTML4.01/XHTML1.0 and some parts of HTML5, as well as some proprietary parts (though HTML5 has specified most of these).

Comment: So, if I am not wrong, it is not possible to distinguish an XHTML 1 document from and XHTML 5 document solely by looking at their prologues, is that right?

Comment: Note that if XHTML document is being served with MIME-type "`application/xml`" or "`application/xhtml+xml`", the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"' namespace declaration may be required by some browsers so as not to consider your document as plain XML...

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good question, covering outstanding issues the W3C is still working on as of late 2012:

Concerning the DOCTYPE question, there could be **new developments** on the **DOCTYPE matter**: as of **Nov. 12th, 2012**, the [HTML5 Latest Editor's Draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#syntax-doctype) states, concerning  the HTML syntax, in section "8.1.1 The DOCTYPE", that:

1. "A DOCTYPE is a required preamble [...]" => `<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. "For the purposes of HTML generators that cannot output HTML markup with [that] short DOCTYPE, a DOCTYPE legacy string may be inserted [...]" => `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">` can be used if absolutely required (e.g. by an XML generator)
3. "To help authors transition from HTML4 and XHTML1, an obsolete permitted DOCTYPE string can be inserted [...]" => e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` (or any of 5 others, see below)

To my understanding:

- all 3 forms hold exactly the same meaning : "this doc is HTML5", no matter what the specific, **legal**, legacy PUBLIC doctype being used for backward-compatibility reasons
- **and** using one of them is **required** (i.e. use the first one, unless you have really good reasons not to)

Unless last-minute edits occurs, this should make it into the HTML5 W3C Candidate Recommendation 08 November 2012.

The XHTML syntax remains unchanged on that matter: "XML documents may contain a DOCTYPE if desired, but this is not required to conform to this specification."

---

To sum it up, starting Nov. 8th, 2012, **any of the following would be valid**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

And:

- **any other doctype invalid**,
- **no doctype at all, invalid HTML**
- and no doctype still an option for XML...

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably the HTML5 specification's [section on XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html#the-xhtml-syntax), which mostly calls out to the [XML 1.0 5th edition spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) and the [namespaces spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/). As it says there, there's no defined DOCTYPE for HTML5 in XML, which is the answer to the DOCTYPE part of your question. It does specifically mention intermixing HTML5 with other content in XML documents, so that should be the answer to that part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

> For example is something like this valid in XHTML 5?

No, and you couldn't do it with XHTML 1 either. Once you start doing FOO + BAR documents, they are not valid FOO or valid BAR, just some combination of the two (which may conform to a DTD and thus be valid FOO + BAR)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?" 
      "WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?">
```

A custom DTD that describes the combination of markup languages you are using.

When mixing namespaces you are usually better off forgetting about DTDs. It isn't going to be HTML compatible anyway, so `text/html` is out of the question

```
<html xmlns="WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?"
       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
```

The XHTML namespace has not changed. This is the same as every other version of XHTML.

Comment: If the XHTML namespace has not changed, then how does a validator know if the document is XHTML 5 so hat elements like <dialog> are valid or if it is XHTML 1 so that <dialog> and other new elements are invalid?

Comment: Namespaces have never had anything to do with validation. You have to use either an explicit XHTML 5 validator or use a schema validator and pass it both a schema and your document.

Comment: So why do we even include a DOCTYPE and reference a DTD, if the XHTML document isn't validated against the DTD? Also, what you say implies that it is not possible to say whether a document is XHTML 1 or XHTML 5 solely by looking at its prologue, or is it?

Comment: Some XHTML documents (including the various flavours of 1.0 and 1.1, and I think there is a 1.0+SVG+MathML around somewhere) are validated against DTDs. XHTML 5 doesn't have a DTD.

Comment: So does this mean that it is impossible to know if an HTML document is XHTML 1 or XHTML 5 simply by looking at its prologue?

Comment: Yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965449/xhtml-5-prologue-vs-xhtml-1-prologue/2965503#2965503

Answer (score -2):

I'm afraid there is no such thing as XHTML5.

You can have either real XHTML, with one of the classic XHTML DOCTYPEs (see other answers), or you can put in the `<!DOCTYPE html>` one, and then it mostly validates, but then it's no longer fully XHTML. It will only work if you treat it as HTML.

For instance, this file

```xhtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head><title>test</title></head>
   <body><p>&nbsp;</p></body>
</html>
```

will only work if you give it a `.html` extension. With `.xhtml`, no way.

You may think that saving as `.html` is no big deal, but then it's HTML, regardless of what the contents of the file say. Then you can just as well throw away the XML declaration and the xmlns attribute and all other XHTML features.

Comment: Not true, there is real XHTML 5. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml

Comment: @sam That section is non normative. My argument still stands. For example, there is no way to tell the W3C validator that your document should be parsed as XHTML5.

Comment: I thought you were arguing there is no such thing. Let me clarify what I'm saying - it is possible to write XHTML 5 (as per the spec) and serve it as application/xhtml+xml. Browsers support this although it has limited use in that regard (see https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/xhtml5 for example). XHTML 5 is also required (an example I happen to know about) as part of the EPUB3 ebook format. There isn't a 'real' doctype for (X)HTML5, but that doesn't matter. I haven't tried the W3C validator with it...