# XHTML 5 Prologue vs XHTML 1 Prologue

Tags: xml, html

Are there any differences between prologues of XHTML 1 and XHTML 5? Is it possible to find out whether a document is XHTML 1 or XHTML 5 simply by looking at its prologue?

Comment: `XHTML 5` does not exist. It is `HTML 5`.

Comment: XHTML 5 is the commonly accepted term for HTML 5 documents that use the XML syntax

Comment: @Quentin yeah, HTML5 is really poorly named, since it's a vocabulary not a markup language: http://www.w3.org/blog/2008/01/html5-is-html-and-xml/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strictly conforming XHTML 1.0 document will include an XHTML 1.0 Doctype.

Non-strictly conforming XHTML 1.0 documents and XHTML 5 documents will not. So it will let you identify some XHTML 1.0 documents, but not all.