# W3C validation problems with FB meta tags + iframes

Tags: facebook, xhtml, meta-tags, w3c-validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Connect Won’t Validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599334/facebook-connect-wont-validate)

I'm working on making our site W3C compliant. Here's the problem:

The "meta property ..." tags require the XHTML+RDF doctype. I use the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
```

The problem is, this doctype does not support iframes and cause them to fail validation. The iframes come from our advertising department (which I have no control over) so I can't just remove/replace them.

Is there a doctype that supports both the "meta property" tag and iframes? If not, how would *you* handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use jquerys $.get function to get the code for the ad?

```
$.GET('http://www.advert.com/clickme.php', function(a) {
    $("#advertdiv").html(a)
});
```

// Edit - just so its clear, your 'clickme.php' would be hosted on your site, then use PHP to pull the data for the ad.

Comment: That would be one solution, yes, but I'd much rather solve this server side.

Comment: are you using any server side tech? you could just use 
    <?php import('advert.php') ?> 
in the place you want the ad.