# W3C Validation - Page not validating with OG: / Facebook tags

Tags: facebook, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Connect Won’t Validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599334/facebook-connect-wont-validate)

I've got the following page I'm working on:

http://www.orangeorb.com/apps/app-page.asp?productid=8

All is good validation wise - but I can't get the Facebook stuff / tags / Meta OG to validate.

Tried a few Doctypes with no joy.

Answer (score 0):

my recommendation : use Facebook useragent

Here is sample code for it :

```
<?php if($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']=='facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)')
{   
echo '  <meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE URL" />
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR FB ID" />
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE NAME" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="description" /> ';
 break;
}
```

Comment: OK - I can see that working for the OG meta tabs, but it won't work for the like button script I guess as we cant use the user agent for that...

I guess one approach would be to use JQuery to add the facebook like button to the DOM after the page loads - would that be OK to do you think?

Comment: this should work for like buttons can you give me a url of your website ?